# Gmail API OAuth redirect issue

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I have website with the following code that works perfectly on my local machine, but on the remote server, it doesn't redirect to Google OAuth to create token.json and gives me a 502 error. Where could I have made a mistake?

I just need to authenticate with OAuth to access my Gmail account and retrieve emails from it. Can't generate token.json.

```
SCOPES = [
    'https://mail.google.com/',
]


def get_gmail_service():
    creds = None
    config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config')
    credentials_path = os.path.join(config_path, 'creds.json')
    token_path = os.path.join(config_path, 'token.json')
    if os.path.exists(token_path):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_path, SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                credentials_path, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open(token_path, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
        try:
            service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
            return service
        except HttpError as error:
            print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

def get_emails():
    service = get_gmail_service()
```

Comment: That code isn't going to run on a web server the consent screen will open on the server not the users Web browser.   I have done it with flask personally

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo
Can I review your code or some documentation with examples? I'm having trouble finding a Gmail API code example with a service return similar to what's in my code (for Web server).

Answer (score 0):

This is my web QuickStart sample.  Let me know if you have any issues with it and I will have a look

```
# https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/wiki/API-access-on-behalf-of-your-clients-%28web-flow%29
import os

import flask
from flask import Flask,redirect,render_template,url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
import google.auth.exceptions
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_cert_chain('C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Python\cert.pem', 'C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Python\key.pem')
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

REDIRECT_URI = 'https://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth2callback'

CREDENTIALS = 'C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\CredWebEverything.json'

def get_flow():

    # Initialize the flow using the client ID and secret downloaded earlier.
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CREDENTIALS,
        scopes= SCOPES,
    )
    # Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
    # the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required.
    flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI

    return flow


def redirect_user():

    flow = get_flow()
    # Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
    # Use kwargs to set optional request parameters.
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
        # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
        access_type='offline',
        # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
        include_granted_scopes='false',
        # Forces a new refresh token when we authorize the application a second time.
        #prompt= "consent"
        )

    return authorization_url, state

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    authorization_url, state = redirect_user()
    return flask.redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route('/listmessages')
def gmail_list_messages():
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        try:
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
            print(f'Credentials exist refreshing.')
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError as error:
            # if refresh token fails, reset creds to none.
            creds = None
            print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            # If it's not logged in then it's going to force it to.
            authorization_url, state = redirect_user()
            print(f'Credentials do not exist requesting authorization.')
            return flask.redirect(authorization_url)
    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Gmail v1 API
        results = service.users().messages().list(
            userId='me').execute()
        messages = results.get('messages', [])
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

    return render_template("mail.html", data=messages)



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title="Home Page")

@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    flow = get_flow()

    auth_code = request.args['code']
    flow.fetch_token(code=auth_code)
    credentials = flow.credentials

    # saving the credentials for later. Note: A refresh does not return a new refresh token.
    if not os.path.exists('token.json') or credentials.refresh_token:
        print(f'Storing credentials: {credentials.to_json()}')
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(credentials.to_json())

    return redirect("/listmessages")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, ssl_context=context)
```